# PHP combobox to textbox get fetch value from database

Tags: php, ajax

```
<head>
    <script> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#combo').change(function(){
                console.log($(this));
            var sqlQuery = "SELECT product_name='combo' from product_master where mrp='textbox'";
            var result = dbConn.executeCachedQuery(sqlQuery);
                $.get( "abc.php");
            $('#combo').change(function(){ $('#textbox').val($(this).val()); });
             } ) ;
         });
    </script>`
</head>
<body>
    <form>
         <select name="combo" id="combo">
             <option value="">-- Select</option>
             <?php  
                    require_once("connect.php");
                $query="select * from product_master";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                   echo '<option value = "' . $row['product_name'] . '">' . $row['product_name'] . '</option>';
                    }
              ?>
        </select>
        <input type="textbox" id="textbox" value="<?php $row['mrp']; ?>" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to fetch from database on selected from combo box into text box.

Same product name fetch mrp. Product name combo box and mrp text box once select combo with same mrp need to fetch.

Comment: use ajax to fetch data and then using DOM place data in your combo box

Comment: post the value to some page, with ajax or jquery post(), get the response and fill in text box

Comment: `  id  int(11)    
 product_name  varchar(200) 
 group  varchar(100)  
 mrp int(100)`

Comment: i want product_name in drop down and when select any product of same product i required mrp in textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready()function(){
    $('#combo').change(function(){
      $.post("abc.php",{combo:$(this.val() )},function(result){
            $("#textbox").val(result);
      });
   });

 });
 </script>
```

In abc.php, pick the value of combo from post and query to database, echo the value,

Comment: `<?php
require_once("connect.php");
$rate= $_POST["textbox"];
$product_name= $_POST["combo"];
  mysql_query("SELECT product_name='$product_name' FROM product_master WHERE mrp='$rate'"); 
?>` this is abc code

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh use @Abuzer Firdousi code for front end. For back end you need to echo your options values. Your `abc.php` code should look like

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
$rate= $_POST["textbox"];
$product_name= $_POST["combo"];
$rs =mysql_query("SELECT mrp FROM product_master WHERE product_name='$product_name'");
if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)){
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
  echo $row->mrp
} 

?>
```

By combinging Abuzar and my answer, your will get your solution :-)

Comment: fetch in to combox box is not a problem but from combox match value from databse and get mrp from database into textbox

Comment: Edit your question and show  your table structure. You have some thing wrong in your query

Comment: `  id  int(11)    
 product_name  varchar(200) 
 group  varchar(100)  
 mrp int(100)`

Comment: ajax or java script on select event

Comment: after check your code also its not working sir, please help me its very urgent

Comment: @Rajesh. As for as I have understood your problem, please check now answer. I have updated my answer

Comment: I think my java script not correct, sorry sir, not i find my solution from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp?output=print from this i taken my logic point and implemented in my project thank you for time and comments thanks once again